# DB2 not accepting UUID

Tags: spring-data-jpa, db2, uuid

I am using UUID datatype for generating alpha numeric primary key. Following is the code:

```
public class Example {

private UUID id;

@Id
@Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, length = 36)
@GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
public UUID getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(UUID id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}
```

The Java code is generating the uuid something like - c70e22b4-d2a8-11ea-87d0-0242ac130003.
But on saving the values in a DB2 table, in UUID column(which is of VARCHAR(25) type in DB2), I am getting values as in table as:

```
<failed to load>
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][t4][1065][12306][4.23.42] Caught java.io.CharConversionException.  See attached Throwable for details. ERRORCODE=-4220, SQLSTATE=null
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ld.a(ld.java:794)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ld.a(ld.java:66)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ld.a(ld.java:125)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.mc.a(mc.java:2963)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.mc.p(mc.java:575)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.mc.P(mc.java:1656)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ResultSet.getStringX(ResultSet.java:1223)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ResultSet.getString(ResultSet.java:1192)
at com.intellij.database.remote.jdbc.impl.RemoteResultSetImpl.tryGetObject(RemoteResultSetImpl.java:1289)
at com.intellij.database.remote.jdbc.impl.RemoteResultSetImpl.getObject(RemoteResultSetImpl.java:1272)
at com.intellij.database.remote.jdbc.impl.RemoteResultSetImpl.getCurrentRow(RemoteResultSetImpl.java:1249)
at com.intellij.database.remote.jdbc.impl.RemoteResultSetImpl.getObjects(RemoteResultSetImpl.java:1229)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:281)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.r.a(r.java:52)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.mc.a(mc.java:2952)
... 25 more
```

Looks like I can not map UUID to Varchar, but not able to find the alternative.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where you got a length of 25 from....

`c70e22b4-d2a8-11ea-87d0-0242ac130003` is 36 characters...

if you want to store the binary value, you only need 16 bytes, but they must for `CHAR(16) FOR BIT DATA`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert text UUID stings in Db2 to binary with the `[VARCHAR_BIT_FORMAT][1]` function

```
CREATE TABLE UUID(U BINARY(16) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)
;
INSERT INTO UUID 
VALUES VARCHAR_BIT_FORMAT(
    'c70e22b4-d2a8-11ea-87d0-0242ac130003'
,   'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
)
```